# PHP OPcache and dynamic variables in pages

Tags: php, caching, php-7, opcache, dynamic-variables

I have read a lot regarding Opcache and how it helps speed up PHP code either in Worpdress, standalone PHP scripts and even in conjunction.

What if one page is used to generate different content for each user based on a dynamic variable `$userid` which is filed only when the user is loggedin.

The `$userid` is used to pull data from a MongoDB database related to that user as well as a data from a Wordpress MySQL database which has additional user info in it (*name, email*).

Is there a chance that Opcache will cache one users content and show it to others instead of each users specific content, or possibly mix up the users and cause huge privacy issues?

In order to explain how it works:

```
profile.php -> has $userid

$userid -> calls MongoDB and MySQL for that users content
```

Content fetched from databases is parsed to other variables inside the page so it is shown in specific spots accordingly (*inside tables, divs, etc*).

Also based on the `$userid` a different function is called inside **profile.php**

Is there a way to exclude variables from OPcache?
Or is there no problem with them and the dynamic content will work fine?

Will OPcache cache the version with no `$userid` and for each user that accesses the poge populate the `$userid` variable based on his logged-in $userid ?

Thank you in advance for any input and help!

Comment: Opcache doesn't cache anything that your code produces, it caches the code itself so that it doesn't have to be pulled off disk and parsed every time.

Comment: @Sammitch what about the content inside the variables that changes for each user? 
For example `$userid` or `$usersidsettings` which are either filled from the databases and are different for each user and based on the `$userid` a different function and `ifstatement` is executed inside the Opcached file (profile.php)?

Comment: Let me revise: Opcache doesn't care about _anything that happens_ when your code executes, because it caches the code itself _before anything executes_. Unless you have physically typed something into a PHP file directly, Opcache won't cache it.